# Ubuntu 20.04 Touchpad cursor jumping

Tags: drivers, 20.04, touchpad

I`m using Ubuntu 20.04.1. After installing video driver for AMD (AMDGPU PRO) i got "Jumping touchpad cursor error". It has totally random movement and also registering clicks randomly. Without video driver i don't have this issue and in BIOS also (so seems like its not touchpad error).

**Notebook**: Asus VivoBook S15 M533IA

**Proc**: Ryzen 5 4500U

**Video**: integrated

Tryed both **synaptics** and **libinput** drivers.

`xinput list` list prints:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY USB Device                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY USB Device Consumer Control       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUE1201:00 04F3:3125 Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUE1201:00 04F3:3125 Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device                        id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device Keyboard               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device System Control         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput list-props 15` prints:

```
Device 'ASUE1201:00 04F3:3125 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (150):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (152): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (280): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (281):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (282):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (283):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (308):  127, 3065, 98, 1726
    Synaptics Finger (309): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (310):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (311):   161
    Synaptics Tap Durations (312):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (313):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (314):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (315):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (316):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (317): -73, 73
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (318): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (319):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (320): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.054407, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (321):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (322):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (323):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (324): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (325):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (326): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (327):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (328): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (329):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (330): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (331):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (332): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (333):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (334): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (335):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (336):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (337):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (338):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (339): 31, 31
    Synaptics Area (340):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (341):  1596, 0, 1495, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (342): 18, 18
    Device Product ID (270):    1267, 12581
    Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event13"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same latop and are experiencing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MarcoMartinelli nah, just returned this and bought a new one.